# "Jerry takes a sip of his drink as Joe and Jack come up to the bar."

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, conjunctions

I have these two sentences that I want to connect.

> Jerry takes a sip of his drink.

and

> Joe and Jack come up to the bar.

- Would it be okay to connect them if they don't really have a connection (besides that Jerry ends up talking to Joe and Jack), they just happen at the same time?
- Could I use "as" to connect them? Or would it sound like Jerry took a sip of his drink because he saw them coming or something?

> Jerry takes a sip of his drink as Joe and Jack come up to the bar.

Comment: Be aware that this site deals with questions about grammar and idiom rather than style. But, in brief, the answer is yes. The implication is that Joe and Jack's arrival will be tied in with Jerry's presence.

Comment: You might want tom ask about style on Writing.SE.